# Increasing memory usage in socket client

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, console-application, asyncsocket

I'm trying to develop a console application behaving as an asynchronous socket client in C#. You can see the code below:

```
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

class Program
{
    private static readonly string hostIp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostIp"];
    private static readonly int port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostPort"]);
    private static Socket client; 
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static Thread receiveThread;

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog appLog = new EventLog();
        appLog.Source = "xApp";

        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostIp);
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "Login Message");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            receiveThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Receive(client);
                    receiveDone.WaitOne();
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            });
            receiveThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            appLog.WriteEntry(
                "An exception occured: " +
                " ex: " + ex.ToString() +
                " stack trace: " + ex.StackTrace,
                System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", state.sb.ToString());
                string[] args = state.sb.ToString().Split(';');
                switch (args[1])  
                {
                    case "CREATEBOOK":
                        ProcessInput(args);
                        break;
                    case "CONFIRMBOOK":
                        if (args[2] == "true")   
                        {
                            ConfirmProcess();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging I see that the code does the work as expected but the memory size used by process is increasing every moment. I think that the reason of the memory leak is the following code piece:

```
receiveThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
{
    while (true)
    {
        Receive(client);
        receiveDone.WaitOne();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
});
receiveThread.Start();
```

But I don't have any idea about the change I have to do. Do you have any tip?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why are you using async IO when you always wait for the result? That gives you the worst of both worlds.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would explain a _continuous_ increase in memory usage. Due to the way GC works, you could see memory usage increase to some point before stabilizing, and that's perfectly normal and acceptable. But note usr's comment: you should not be waiting for I/O completion in a loop if you're going to use `BeginReceive()`. Instead, just call `BeginReceive()`, and then call it again from your completion callback to start the next receive. Post [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you think you have a real memory leak issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `Receive` method which you are calling in a `while` loop. Basically you are creating a new `StateObject` every time you loop around.

```
// Create the state object.
StateObject state = new StateObject();
```

Try and store the state object as a class variable and reuse it. Maybe add a `Reset` method if you need to re-initialilze it again. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) shows a way to build a very efficient asynchronous socket which you may find useful.